# Channel subscribers gets banned if added using Telethon API, How to Unban it?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am using Telethon API for adding members to my channel from a group, But the users who have been added to my channel gets ban immediately after adding, So they are not added but gets banned.

How to unban them? using telethon API

Inviting them with:

```
client(EditBannedRequest(
            channel, user, ChannelBannedRights(
                until_date=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
                view_messages=True
            )

      client(InviteToChannelRequest(
            channel,
            [ user ]
        ))
```

With some exceptions like:

```
    except UserNotMutualContactError as e:
    except UserPrivacyRestrictedError as e:
    except PeerFloodError as e:
    except FloodWaitError as e:
```

I am giving the rights:

```
 rights = ChannelAdminRights(
                                     change_info=False,
                                     post_messages=False,
                                     edit_messages=None,
                                     delete_messages=True,
                                     invite_users=True,
                                     pin_messages=True,
                                     ban_users=None,
                                     add_admins=True )
                       client(EditAdminRequest(channel, user, rights))
```

My channel recent action shows "Banned username"

The help would be really appreciated.
Thank you